# Python/Pyrogram on Mac Server Suddenly Turning up Error 61 Connection Refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, telegram, pyrogram

I have a Pyrogram app that has been running for ages with no problems from a server running MacOS.  A few days ago, the code suddenly hung up and refuses to work.  As soon as I attempt to start the Pyrogram Client(), I immediately get "Err 61 Connection Refused"/"network issues" errors.  I have confirmed that my Telegram API account is totally fine.  The next assumption was that it was an IP ban issue, but I can't even get the Client to open a socket to an http proxy.  Pyrogram documentation has nothing about an Error 61, and now I'm thinking that the problem isn't with Pyrogram but rather with a core Python library (corrupted?).

I have seen references on Stackoverflow to folks running into analogous problems with other Python api/web applications but not randomly after a year of normal operation.  Some of them were able to resolve the issue by switching references to "localhost" to "127.0.0.1", but I have no idea where that would be located within the Pyrogram library, nor why that would suddenly be a problem out of the blue with no code or server changes.

Help! ;)  Thanks!!

Update:

I forgot to post code:

```
import os
import logging
from typing import List, Tuple, Optional
import re
import math
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

import asyncio
import pyrogram
import yaml
import time
import base64
import sys
import mysql.connector
import subprocess

client = pyrogram.Client(
   "media_downloader",
   api_id,
   api_hash,
)
```

... and there it ends.

```
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 61] Connection refused
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: [Errno 61] Connection refused
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/home/telegram/get_message_media_v2.py", line 99, in <module>
    with client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 251, in __enter__
    return self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1854, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/selectors.py", line 562, in select
    kev_list = self._selector.control(None, max_ev, timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

After attempting with a proxy:

```
INFO:pyrogram.connection.transport.tcp.tcp:Using proxy [PROXY REDACTED]
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
WARNING:pyrogram.connection.connection:Unable to connect due to network issues: Socket error: timed out
INFO:pyrogram.connection.transport.tcp.tcp:Using proxy [PROXY REDACTED]
INFO:pyrogram.connection.connection:Connecting...
^X^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/home/telegram/get_message_media_v2.py", line 106, in <module>
    with client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 251, in __enter__
    return self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 52, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py", line 46, in connect
    await self.session.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 105, in start
    await self.connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/connection/connection.py", line 57, in connect
    await self.protocol.connect(self.address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/connection/transport/tcp/tcp_abridged_o.py", line 40, in connect
    await super().connect(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/connection/transport/tcp/tcp.py", line 82, in connect
    self.socket.connect(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 443, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self.proxy_peername, self.proxy_sockname = self._SOCKS5_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 470, in _SOCKS5_request
    chosen_auth = self._readall(reader, 2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socks.py", line 276, in _readall
    d = file.read(count - len(data))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into this problem, I was able to eventually resolve this by using pip3 to reinstall/upgrade Pyrogram.  I still don't know the exact underlying cause, and at this point, I can only assume that either my copy of Pyrogram got corrupted somehow, or else there were changes to Telegram that broke a slightly older version of Pyrogram (I had 1.7.1 installed previously and pip upgraded it to 2.0.35).

```
pip3 install pyrogram --upgrade
```